# Angularjs can't loop with ng-repeat if key has colon ":"

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a problem to loop a simple json in angularjs with `ng-repeat`. The json is this one:

```
$scope.lines = { 
        data: [
                { "properties": {
                    "name": "My test",
                    "test:testOne": "This is test one" }
                }
        ]
    };
```

and the problem is this: `test:testOne`. I need to parse that property but i don't know how do it because it has the colon. I made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/1250/ in which i tried some ways but without success

Comment: What do you mean by you wanted to parse `"test:testOne"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation), like so

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="line in lines.data">
       {{ line.properties['test:testOne'] }}
       {{ line.properties.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/1251/)

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you!